# Javascript toggle slide nav with fade

Tags: javascript, html, css

Click the flower to open menu. Then i have created the motion i want with "prosess" fading in after the menu opens up. But i want to reverse the motion when collapsing. So that "prosess" fades out before the meny toggles back. Anyone that can help me out with this?

```js
function classOpen() {
    var spinn = document.getElementById("nav");

    spinn.classList.toggle('in');
    spinn.classList.toggle('out');
}

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
    const classFadeIn = async () => {

    var element1 = document.getElementById("text1");
    var element2 = document.getElementById("text2");
    var element3 = document.getElementById("text3");

    await delay(300);

    element1.classList.toggle("show");
    element2.classList.toggle("show");
    element3.classList.toggle("show");
}

    document.querySelector('#nav').addEventListener('click', classFadeIn);
```

```css
:root{
  --seconds: 5s;
  --fast: 2s;
}

nav{
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav img{
  width: 50px;
}

/* INN OUT */

#nav{
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-right: 20px;

    /*drop shadow*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);

}
.in {
    width: 50px;
}

.out {
    width: 400px;

}
.transition{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition::all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


#navtext{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.style{
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: lightgrey;
  transition: 0.1s;

}
#text{
  display: none;
}
.noshow{
  display: none;
}
.show{
  display: flex;
}

.show:hover{
  color: black;
  background-color: lightgrey
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="nav" class="in transition">
    <img id="spinn" src="https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/762080_preview_preview.png" class="rotating spinn" onclick="classOpen()">
    <div id="navtext">
        <a id="text1" class="noshow style">Prosess</a>
        <a id="text2" class="noshow style">Prosess</a>
        <a id="text3" class="noshow style">Prosess</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted the part for showing/hiding the items from Javascript and kept `in/out` toggle.

Then, depending on `in/out` classes I will show/hide the items by CSS:

```
.transition.in .noshow{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  height:0;
}
.transition.out .noshow{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  height:auto;
  transition: 0.7s;
}
```

The reason for not using `display: none || flex` is to keep the effect of transitoin.

Here is the full code:

```js
function classOpen() {
    var spinn = document.getElementById("nav");

    spinn.classList.toggle('in');
    spinn.classList.toggle('out');
}

document.querySelector('#nav').addEventListener('click', null);
```

```css
:root{
  --seconds: 5s;
  --fast: 2s;
}

nav{
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav img{
  width: 50px;
}

/* INN OUT */

#nav{
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-right: 20px;

    /*drop shadow*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);

}
.in {
    width: 50px;
}

.out {
    width: 400px;

}
.transition{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition::all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


#navtext{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.style{
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: lightgrey;
  transition: 0.1s;

}
#text{
  display: none;
}
.transition.in .noshow{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  height:0;
}
.transition.out .noshow{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  height:auto;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.noshow:hover{
  color: black;
  background-color: lightgrey
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="nav" class="in transition">
    <img id="spinn" src="https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/762080_preview_preview.png" class="rotating spinn" onclick="classOpen()">
    <div id="navtext">
        <a id="text1" class="noshow style">Prosess</a>
        <a id="text2" class="noshow style">Prosess</a>
        <a id="text3" class="noshow style">Prosess</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use only one `"is-active"` class-name** on the `#nav` element, toggle it using JS and target descendants using CSS.

Use `transition-delay` CSS property to smartly inverse the transition timing login on toggle:

```js
const nav = document.querySelector("#nav");
nav.addEventListener("click", () => nav.classList.toggle("is-active"));
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#navImg {
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

#nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
}

#navText {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#navText a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: #aaa;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

/* ACTIVE STATE */
#nav.is-active #navText {
  transition-delay: 0s; /* reverse delay timing logic */
  width: 270px; /* this could be calculated using JS... this is for demo only */
}
#nav.is-active #navText a {
  transition-delay: 0.3s; /* reverse delay timing logic */
  opacity: 1;
}
#nav.is-active #navImg {
  transform: rotate(1turn);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="nav">
    <img id="navImg" src="https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/762080_preview_preview.png">
    <div id="navText">
      <a href="#!">Prosess</a>
      <a href="#!">Prosess</a>
      <a href="#!">Prosess</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```